# uploading files and inserting its path in mysql column using php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

**i have this file

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="add") 
{  

     $CompanyName=$_POST['add_CompanyName'];
     $SupplierAddress=$_POST['add_SupplierAddress'];
     $SupplierFax1=$_POST['add_SupplierFax1'];   $pattern="/^[A-Z]{2}\d{4}\b/";


     if(($CompanyName=="")||($SupplierAddress == "")||($SupplierFax1 == "")){
       echo '{"status":"1"}';
       exit;
     }
     else if( !preg_match($pattern,$SupplierFax1)){
       echo  '{"status":"2"}';
       exit;
     }else{
       $test=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO suppliers(CompanyName,SupplierAddress,SupplierFax1,AttachTitle) VALUES('$CompanyName','$SupplierAddress','$SupplierFax1')") or die ("data error!");
       echo '{"status":"3"}';
       exit; 
     }
}
elseif(isset($_POST['action'])&& $_POST['action']=="update") 
{      
     $id=$_POST['edit_id'];
     $CompanyName=$_POST['edit_CompanyName'];
     $SupplierAddress=$_POST['edit_SupplierAddress'];
     $SupplierFax1=$_POST['edit_SupplierFax1'];

     $test = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE suppliers SET CompanyName='$CompanyName',SupplierAddress='$SupplierAddress',SupplierFax1='$SupplierFax1', WHERE id='$id'") or die ("data error!");
     echo '{"status":"3"}';
     exit;
  }
elseif(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="delete") 
{

     $id = $_POST['delete_id'];
     $test = mysqli_query($con,"delete from suppliers where id='$id'");
     if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1){ 
       echo '{"status":"1"}';
     }else{
       echo '{"status":"0"}';
     }
     exit;
}
```

and  i have this  form

```
<form id="form1" method="post" enctype=”multipart/form-data>
    <p><label>CompanyName</label><input type="text" id="add_CompanyName" name="add_CompanyName" /></p>
    <p><label>SupplierAddress</label><input type="text" id="add_SupplierAddress" name="add_SupplierAddress" /> </p>
    <p><label>SupplierFax1</label><input type="text" id="add_SupplierFax1" name="add_SupplierFax1" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Add" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="add" />
</form>
```

now  i want to add new two   fields to upload documents and show  their  path in  mysql  with the path description
how can  i add them  to the above code  ? 
am  using also  ajax

```
 $('#suppliers tr:even:not(#nav):not(#total)').addClass('even');
 $('#suppliers tr:odd:not(#nav):not(#total)').addClass('odd') 

 $("form#form1").submit(function(){
    var vId = $("input#edit_id").val();                  
    var vCompanyName = $("input#edit_CompanyName").val();                
    var vSupplierAddress = $("input#edit_SupplierAddress").val();         
    var vSupplierFax1 = $("input#edit_SupplierFax1").val();             
    var myRegExp=/^[A-Z]{2}\d{4}\b/;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do first is alter your table with the new data fields you need.
For instance:

```
ALTER TABLE supplies ADD COLUMN field2 varchar(32) NOT NULL;
```

To fill this column you will have to add this to your HTML:

```
 <p><label>Field2</label><input type="text" id="add_field2" name="add_field2" /></p>
```

And catch this in PHP like:

```
$field2 = $_POST['add_field2'];
```

and alter your insert query to look something like:

```
     $test=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO suppliers(CompanyName,SupplierAddress,SupplierFax1,AttachTitle, field2) VALUES('$CompanyName','$SupplierAddress','$SupplierFax1', '$field2')") or die ("data error!");
```

and your update query:

```
     $test = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE suppliers SET CompanyName='$CompanyName',SupplierAddress='$SupplierAddress',SupplierFax1='$SupplierFax1',field2='$field2' WHERE id='$id'") or die ("data error!");
```

I also want to point you to the following site: [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Read this carefully to prevent your database will be compromised if your application is open to the world

Comment: okay i've created a new column  " documents"  and added  it in html form and php  form as above  , now can i set the path  of  uploaded documents  in it  ?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with this column.

Comment: okay  i've created uploads folder and  give it  777 permission and inserted in it a document , how can i insert this  path  in a specific  id in mysql as a link